# Error calling php-script from Ajax: Invalid XML

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, get

I am trying to make the following jQuery-code to call my php-script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="parser/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="parser/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $ (document).ready(function() {
            currCity = "ROME (FCO)";
            $.ajax({
                url: 'parser/php/get_data.php', 
                type: "GET",
                data: currCity, 
                dataType: "json",    
                success: function(array){
                    alert ("AJAX succeeded!");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(jqXHR.status + "    " + textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Even when I was just using a simple php-script, like this one (without the data type and a callback value in the success-function):

```
<?php
   echo "Got here";
?>
```

I got the following errors:

```
200    parsererror

demo.html (line 17)
Error: Invalid XML: <?php echo "Got here"; ?>
```

So that's the first error I'm trying to solve, Ajax seems to recognize my php-script as xml.
Now this is the actual php-script I need to run. Extract some data from a database, create a two-levels-array to store them and give that array back to Ajax in a JSON.

```
<?php
require 'mysql_login.php';

if (isset($_GET['currCity'])) {
    $str = $_GET['currCity']; 
    echo "Got the value: " + $str;
} 

$db = new mysqli( $mysqlhost, $mysqluser, $mysqlpwd, $airplaneDB) or die ("Connection to database failed".$db->connect_error);
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Airplanes ORDER BY time") or die ("Problem retreiving data from database.");

$planes = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $flightData = {$row['flightID'], $row['flightLink'], $row['orig'], $row['dest'], $row['time']};
    array_push($planes, $flightData);
}

echo json_encode($planes);
?>
```

There, I seem to have trouble recognizing the JSON, here's the error:

```
200    parsererror

demo.html (line 17)
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

return window.JSON.parse( data );
```

Comment: `Error: Invalid XML: <?php echo "Got here"; ?>` suggests your php page isn't being processed by php because it's actually a .html page. The same thing is happening with your second error.

Comment: Also, why are you including two somewhat equivalent versions of jQuery rather than just one or the other?

Comment: How could it possibly a .html-page? The file's called get_data.php, and in the first case all the content was the one I copied here, e.g. there was no sign of html there
You're right about jQuery, had some trouble with that so included both, but the newer one should do just fine

Comment: I'm looking specifically at your error. The error says your server is returning unprocessed php. I was wrong about demo.html, but the error still suggests that your server is returning unprocessed php. Do you even have php installed?

Comment: Make a `<?php phpInfo(); ?>` info.php and navigate to it in your browser.

Comment: It's giving me a long table with all the info, I'm using PHP 5.5.1
Just opened another simple demo in the browser, it worked just fine

Comment: In your error callback, `console.log(jqXHR.responseText)`

Comment: <?php
 echo "Got here";
?>

Comment: And that confirms that your php code isn't being processed. Instead, it's being returned as raw text. this is either a file-name issue, or a server config issue. since your phpInfo() test worked, i'm still assuming it's a filename issue.

Comment: So this means the right document was found, but not processed by php, and instead the sheer php-code is returned. The file name and path seem to be alright, since the code at least is being returned. What else could I try?

Comment: Try navigating to said file using your browser instead

Comment: You were right, I tried it normal php-files as well, they didn't get handled right from the browser. Had some trouble on the network, looks like it it wracked XAMPP. Gonna get this fixed, try it again and update the question

Comment: Find any solution? I think I'm facing a same issue, no clue why I get the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065439/invalid-xml-format-how-to-avoid-this