# Invalid XML format - How to avoid this

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, xml

I'm getting data from a database in PHP/mysql, which has invalid characters, such as &. I'm creating the XML as follows:

```
$stmt->bind_result($foo)|| fail('An error occurred: MySQL bind_result', $db->error);

$foo=htmlspecialchars($foo, ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8');


$xmlstr = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes">
<xml>";
while ($stmt->fetch())
{ $xmlstr.="
             <RECORD>
               <FOO>$foo</FOO>
             </RECORD>";}
  $xmlstr.="
  </xml>";

$stmt->close();

echo $xmlstr;
```

I'm trying to receive the data and put in an array with javascript - but it gives me the error Invalid XML format. I'm receiving random records and sometimes it does work. So it seems to me that the issue is in the characters coming from the database.

The error occurs here in JavaScript:

```
var foo;
var  formData = "label="+label;  //Name value Pair

 $.ajax({
            url: './php/foo.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data : formData,
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function(returnedXMLResponse){


                $('RECORD', returnedXMLResponse).each(function(){
                     foo = $('FOO', this).text();

                })
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                    console.log("Status: " + textStatus); console.log("Error: " + errorThrown); 
}
       });
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldnt this line 
`$xmlstr = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes">
<xml>"; `
be
`$xmlstr = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>";` I'm looking at examples from http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_usedfor.asp on how an xml file is supposed to look, i also dont see a </xml> in their example.

Comment: `$xmlstr = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes">
<xml>";`  Either php is remarkably intelligent or remarkably dumb.  I'm guessing the problem lies in the fact that you didn't escape your quotation marks.

Comment: Are you sure that you get UTF-8 from the database? Any way I suggest using an XML API like XMLWriter or DOM.

Comment: `&` has a special meaning in XML, pretty much same as in HTML. Therefor, when you mean it _literally_, you have to write it as `&amp;`. `htmlspecialchars` can do that for you – it is “enough” for most possible cases to create valid XML element text content. Using `CDATA` sections would be another possibility.

Comment: I definitely forgot the question mark, but issue still persists even with XMLwriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of the parse error by adding a header:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml = new XMLWriter('UTF-8', '1.0'); 
$xml->openURI('php://output'); 
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startDocument(); 

$xml->startElement("XML"); 
while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
    $xml->startElement("ITEM");
    $xml->writeElement('ELEMENT', $reviewdate);
    $xml->endElement(); // </ITEM>
}
$stmt->close();
$xml->endElement(); // xml

$xml->flush();

unset($xml);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [XMLWriter](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) to ensure correct encoding and such.

```
<?php
$stmt = new Dummy;
$stmt->bind_result($foo);

$xml = new XMLWriter(); 
$xml->openURI('php://output'); 
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startDocument(); 

$xml->startElement("xml"); 
while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
    $xml->startElement("RECORD");
    $xml->writeElement('FOO', $foo);
    $xml->endElement(); // RECORD
}
$xml->endElement(); // xml


class Dummy {
    public function bind_result(&$var) {
        $this->var = &$var;
    }

    public function fetch() {
        static $arr = array('Barnes & Noble', 'Barnum & Bailey', "Buy'n'Large");
        if ( current($arr) ) {
            $this->var = current($arr);
            next($arr);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting, somehow the htmlspecialchars leaves chars like & in the xml - which I'm guessing is the issue. What does the Dummy class do?

Comment: I used this approach, thank, I think it's better. It did not solve my problem. Which is strange. I checked the XML: http://xmlgrid.net/validator.html and it says that it's a well-formatted XML. I've posted the JavaScript where the error occurs

Comment: `class Dummy` just emulates your bind_result/fetch without a database backend to make the example an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) - in other words: it's just boilerplate ;-)

Comment: Does your script output anything before? A whitespace, a BOM, ...anything?

Answer (score 3):

The characters you're getting from the database are not invalid. <, >, & and such are perfectly legal text and can be included in an XML document. However because they have special meaning to an XML parser they need to be escaped. That is:

- `&` --> &amp;
- > --> &gt;
- < --> &lt;

By far the easiest way to do this is not to build the XML by string concatenation as your code sample attempts to do. Instead use a library that automatically escapes characters as necessary as the document is constructed.  XMLWriter has already been suggested. [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) is another option.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking in the browsers network traffic and analyzing the xhr response body to see what your browser is getting as far as the xml payload (data). You can do this in Chrome or IE using F12 developer tools, or if you want to catch it using another proxy, take a look at Fiddler:

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Hope this helps!